# Is there any standard defined for Javascript showModalDialog method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am displaying data in GridView control (Visual Studio 2008). My client has asked to show a dialog once user clicks a cell but he has asked it as a **modal** window. This is to edit a cell. In-cell editing cannot be used because information to be collected is complex and would require lot of controls along with another GridView.

After searching on net, I came to know that showModalDialog Javascript method (on Window object) would work - seems that it works in FF and IE and that's sufficient for me.

Now my question : Is there any standard body (or recommendation) which defines Javascript Window object (and consequently its showModalDialog method)?

I know Standard ECMA-262 ECMAScript Language Specification defines just core Javascript. When I looked at various standards (or recommendations) set by W3C - XHTML, DOM, etc. But I could not find any standard (or recommendation) for Window object.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog says:

"Introduced by Microsoft Internet Explorer 4. Support added to Firefox in Firefox 3, and to Safari in Safari 5.1."

And:

"....is currently being standardized as part of HTML5."

Answer (score 0):

This may not address it directly as I think you are questioning the standard. Personally I'd recommend using jQuery's dialog (from jQueryUi). To me its the easiest to understand, extend, write themes for (using jQuery theme roller), etc. and it integrates nicely with asp.net web forms and mvc. Outside of worrying about the standard, it it supported cross browser.